# Fastest way to pick m distinct objects from a given pattern?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Given an array of n elements, where every element is in the range of 2 to 10^5. Now, if we paint the elements of the array such that for every m(m <= n) consecutive elements no two elements have the same color. How do I pick M distinct elements (not necessarily consecutive) such that no two of the chosen elements have the same colour and the difference between the largest element and smallest element among the choosen elements is the smallest possible?

Ex: for n = 4, A={10 20 15 28} m = 2, we can paint the elements as R G R G or G R G R. In both cases, if we pick any m consecutive elements no two elements have the same color like R G or G R or R G. There are 4 ways to pick 2 elements 10 20 or 10 28 or 20 15 or 15 28. but 20 - 15 = 5 and this is the best answer.

** duplicates allowed in array

My approach to this is to initially put all like colour elements in seperate arrays. Like in the example above i can do:[[10,15][20,28]] 10 15 are R, 20 28 are G. then i use recursion on every element of R and try all comibonations with consecutive colours.

```
void recurse(List<List<Integer>> bs, int max, int min, int depth) {
    if(depth == bs.size()) {
        int diference = max - min;
        // compare diff with old res here
        return;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<bs.get(depth).size();++i) {
        int newMax = Math.max(max,bs.get(depth).get(i));
        int newMin = Math.min(min,bs.get(depth).get(i));
        recurse(bs, newMax, newMin, depth+1);
    }
}
```

This is not wrong and does produces the correct result. But Im looking for a faster algorithm. Expected time complexity is O(n) or in better words i want to pass every test cases in 1 second. Note that 2 <= m <= n <= 10^5

Comment: At first glance this looks like a [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) problem. You may be able to optimise this by means of memoisation.

Comment: @Emily dynamic programming using recursion or iterative?

Comment: Doesn't matter, both ways are pretty much equivalent (iirc).

Comment: *Expected time complexity is O(n)* - you expect that or the task giver?

Comment: @tevemadar i expect that but n log n is fine too i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could order the numbers (but keeping track of their colors), and then walk through the result from its start, first growing a candidate to have all the colors present (so the `head` will cover an unique color in the sublist), then shrinking it so repeated colors are thrown from the `tail` (so it points at a unique color too), then check if it is the best candidate so far, then throw away the `tail` (so that color will be missing), and proceed again with head:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class NewClass {
    public static void doThing(int nums[],int m){
        int n=nums.length;
        ColorNumber l[]=new ColorNumber[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            l[i]=new ColorNumber(nums[i], i%m);
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(l));
        Arrays.sort(l, null);
        List printlist=Arrays.asList(l);
        System.out.println(printlist);
        int present[]=new int[m];
        int head=0,tail=0;
        int minhead=0,mintail=0,mindiff=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        while(head<n){
            System.out.println("try growing");
            int i=0;
            while(i<m && head<n){
                while(present[i]==0 && head<n){
                    present[l[head].color]++;
                    head++;
                }
                //if(present[i]>0)i++;           // the bug
                while(i<m && present[i]>0)i++;   // the fix
            }
            if(i==m){
                System.out.println(printlist.subList(tail, head));
                System.out.println("try shrinking");
                while(present[l[tail].color]>1){
                    present[l[tail].color]--;
                    tail++;
                }
                int diff=l[head-1].number-l[tail].number;
                System.out.println(printlist.subList(tail, head)+" diff: "+diff);
                if(diff<mindiff){minhead=head;mintail=tail;mindiff=diff;}
                present[l[tail].color]--;
                tail++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("min: "+mindiff+", "+printlist.subList(mintail, minhead));
    }

    static class ColorNumber implements Comparable<ColorNumber>{
        final int number;
        final int color;

        public ColorNumber(int number, int color) {
            this.number = number;
            this.color = color;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(ColorNumber o) {
            return number-o.number;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return number+"("+color+")";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Random r=new Random(0);
        int nums[]=new int[10];
        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
            nums[i]=r.nextInt(100);
        doThing(nums, 3);
        System.out.println("---");
        doThing(new int[]{10,20,15,28},2);
        System.out.println("---");
        doThing(new int[] {2,1},2);              // test case for bug
    }
}
```

The output (one 3-color constant random sequence - because a seed is provided -, your 2-color example and the test case for the bug you fixed):

> ```
> [60(0), 48(1), 29(2), 47(0), 15(1), 53(2), 91(0), 61(1), 19(2), 54(0)]
> [15(1), 19(2), 29(2), 47(0), 48(1), 53(2), 54(0), 60(0), 61(1), 91(0)]
> try growing
> [15(1), 19(2), 29(2), 47(0)]
> try shrinking
> [15(1), 19(2), 29(2), 47(0)] diff: 32
> try growing
> [19(2), 29(2), 47(0), 48(1)]
> try shrinking
> [29(2), 47(0), 48(1)] diff: 19
> try growing
> [47(0), 48(1), 53(2)]
> try shrinking
> [47(0), 48(1), 53(2)] diff: 6
> try growing
> [48(1), 53(2), 54(0)]
> try shrinking
> [48(1), 53(2), 54(0)] diff: 6
> try growing
> [53(2), 54(0), 60(0), 61(1)]
> try shrinking
> [53(2), 54(0), 60(0), 61(1)] diff: 8
> try growing
> min: 6 [47(0), 48(1), 53(2)]
> ---
> [10(0), 20(1), 15(0), 28(1)]
> [10(0), 15(0), 20(1), 28(1)]
> try growing
> [10(0), 15(0), 20(1)]
> try shrinking
> [15(0), 20(1)] diff: 5
> try growing
> min: 5 [15(0), 20(1)]
> ---
> [2(0), 1(1)]
> [1(1), 2(0)]
> try growing
> [1(1), 2(0)]
> try shrinking
> [1(1), 2(0)] diff: 1
> min: 1, [1(1), 2(0)]
> ```

In the output only the color of the lowest and the highest value is going to be unique, the in-between elements can be picked at will as they do not contribute to the difference (this code outputs them all like in case of the last attempt in the first sequence (`[53(2), 54(0), 60(0), 61(1)]`)). If a specific output is needed, some `Set` could be used, or a `for` loop over the colors, printing only one (the first one it encounters) element for each color (and skipping the rest with a simple `break`).

Comment: @גלעדברקן Vaguely, yes. Actually, no. Yours leave a lot for imagination, and those parts can be imagined in different implementations. This is an actual implementation, and even the explanation provided for it is different.

Comment: It's not really different. You described a sliding window of unique colouring over a list sorted by value. That was the idea I proposed. (You are correct in that I did not suggest a specific implementation.)

Comment: @גלעדברקן *Iterate over the sorted, labeled list with a sliding window of size m, allowing only one element of each colour to stay in the window at any one time.* is super-ambiguous in your description. I never say it is a fixed size window (which it is not), nor that it contains one element for each color (because when there are repeated colors, on `tail` the highest value is needed, on `head` the lowest one - so it is about tracking multiple values for one color). Only `head` and `tail` are unique for me and I do not take care about between, as I actually say at the end.

Comment: @tevemadar your code fails(wrong answer) for few test cases but I cant figure them out. Any idea?

Comment: @tevemadar all i know it happens for n between 300 to 500.

Comment: @DavidNaga So it is sent to some automatic evaluator. What output format does it expect?

Comment: @tevemadar interger of the minimum possible difference. I was thinking could our difference go below -ve in any way?

Comment: @DavidNaga I think `diff` should not go below zero, an element of lower index is subtracted from an element of higher index, in an ordered array.

Comment: @tevemadar it fails when n = 2,m = 2, nums={1000000000,1}

Comment: @tevemadar basically it fails whenever n = m

Comment: @tevemadar I found the mistake!!!. This line " if(present[i]>0)i++;" is wrong . You need to appy a while loop to that. It should be "while(i < m && present[i]>0) {
                        i++;
                    }"

Comment: @DavidNaga great analysis, edited your fix into the code. Also added an embarassingly simple test case for it, `[2,1]` with 2 colors.

Answer (score 3):

We can solve this in `O(n log n)` time and `O(n)` space. First notice that any assigned colour must be a distance of `m` elements from its neighbours of the same colour or we would invalidate the constraints.

Separate each such list of elements of the same colour (defined only by their distance from each other) into its own list and sort it.

Now merge all the `m` sorted lists into one sorted list where each value is also paired with a label to the colour of the list it came from (the merged list could be of tuples, for example).

(Alternatively, we could first create the entire labeled list and just sort *that*.)

Iterate over the sorted, labeled list with a sliding window of size `m`, allowing only one element of each colour to stay in the window at any one time. (We could use a hash map or simple array to track the window. Remember that the window in this case is of unique labels, not a consecutive subarray of the labeled list.) Update the smallest range existing in the window during the iteration to determine the answer.